# Ionic 4 Ios app rejected because of UIWebView (ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage)

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4 and I uploaded my app on the app store but got rejected due to ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage UIWebView.

[image]

I got this mail from the Apple team.

My ionic info:

```
mac@macs-iMac myApp % ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 22 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0)   : 1.4.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.11.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v14.17.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.12
   OS         : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode      : Xcode 12.5.1 Build version 12E507

mac@macs-iMac myApp %
```

Plugin list:

```
mac@macs-iMac myApp % ionic cordova plugin list
> cordova plugin ls
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 5.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook-connect 3.2.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 3.2.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 7.0.2 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.4.1 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 3.0.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple 0.1.2 "cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 6.0.3 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-deeplinks 1.0.22 "Ionic Deeplink Plugin"
mac@macs-iMac myApp %
```

package json file:

```
{
  "name": "sidemenuTabs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.16",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.13",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "ionic4-star-rating": "^1.1.1",
    "ios-deploy": "^1.11.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-paypal": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "properties-parser": "^0.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "socket.io": "^4.2.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.11.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.16",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "1.5.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.9",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple": "^0.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.24",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires 
        photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo 
      library access to function properly."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect": {
        "APP_ID": "APP_ID",
        "APP_NAME": "MyApp",
        "FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME_SUFFIX": " ",
        "OTHER_APP_SCHEMES": " ",
        "FACEBOOK_AUTO_LOG_APP_EVENTS": "true",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ADVERTISER_ID_COLLECTION": "true",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "11.3.0",
        "FACEBOOK_IOS_SDK_VERSION": "11.1.0",
        "FACEBOOK_BROWSER_SDK_VERSION": "v11.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID",
        "WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID": "WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID"
      },
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "myApp",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "http",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "myapp.domain.in",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "IOS_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "~> 7.4.0"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help...

Comment: First of all your question is wrong. App is rejected because of UIWebView not WKWebView.

Comment: some of your Plugin is using Deprecated `UIWebView`. most probably `cordova-plugin-facebook-connect ` or `cordova-plugin-badge`. or could be any plugins. these 2 are my guess.

Comment: looks like `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` this plugin. Update your Plugins and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

By December 2020, even if your app is already live on the App Store, you will no longer be able to upload new versions of it if those new versions use UIWebView.

You should use WKWebView instead of UIWebView and upload new versions of your app on App Store. This is the only solutions for your problem.

Comment: how can i WKWebView instead of UIWebView?

Comment: First check you used UIWebView or any third party library internally used UIWebView. If you used then you can follow any tutorial how to use WKWebView. In case third party sdk internally using UIWebView then you should not use that sdk or third party library. You can go with different SDK which uses WKWebView.

Comment: I added my package JSON file at end of the question, could please help...

Comment: Can you just search UIWebView in throughout project. You get better understanding which dependencies using UIWebView.

Comment: I searched UIWebView but no result was found.

Comment: Please go through this link https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while uploading an Angular + Cordova app to the app store. However, I have used the following steps which fixed the issue for me.

**Step 1: Install the following two Cordova plugins** -

1. [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine)
2. [cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix) (this plugin is now deprecated but you can follow its github readme for the substitute)

**Step 2: Add the following line to your config.xml** -

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

**Step 3: Rebuild your app and reupload**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bigger issue at large here that isn't being addressed: [The OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70471984/3971390) is attempting to maintain an Ionic Version 4 app that, according to the [Drifty support policy](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/support), is no longer supported. There is a very basic reason for this: It simply is not designed to work on current versions of operating systems.

Ionic developers need to be aware that the apps we develop are not maintainable indefinitely.The expectation is that, as newer versions of the framework are released, we update our apps to the new framework.